# sed replace string with condition

Tags: unix, sed

I have one file contains several lines, each line has the format like

```
2011-07-10 condition hhh aaa: value bbb
2011-07-10 condition ccc aaa: value bbb
```

I want to use sed to find the value string, which is between "aaa:" and "bbb", and replace to "gotit" based on the condition that the string following condition is ccc. and after sed, this file becomes

```
  2011-07-10 condition hhh aaa: value bbb
  2011-07-10 condition ccc aaa: gotit bbb
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given my limited knowledge of sed/regex:

```
sed 's/\(condition ccc.*aaa: \).*\( bbb$\)/\1gotit\2/' file
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't said it clearly, between ccc and aaa, there are some other text, it just ccc have to appear in this line.

Comment: Fair enough, try this then: `sed 's/\(condition ccc.*aaa: \).*\( bbb$\)/\1gotit\2/' file`

Answer (score 4):

Heres more logical:

```
sed '/ccc/{ s/\(.*aaa: \).*\( bbb\)/\1gotit\2/g }' inputfile
```

`sed` operates only on the line that contains `ccc`

Comment: Sorry to hijack your thread. If I want to search & replace for two strings "ccc" and "eee" which is part of a larger string, how do I do it? `sed '/ccc*\|eee*/{ s/\(.*aaa: \).*\( bbb\)/\1gotit\2/g }' inputfile`